# How play some video from itunes movie folder

Tags: video, itunes

My client have ask me an application that can play some video that are inside the ipad movie folder.

My client want sync his video file by itunes and play it from my application.

Comment: any update of this question ? I have the same requirement...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way in the iOS SDK to play user video that was synced onto the device such as The Avengers with one exception. You can play video if it is in the user's camera roll/ photo library with the UIImagePicker.